# Fragment callback on attach complete in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to get the attach complete of a fragment in the hosting activity? I am new to Android.

Here is my code to add a fragment:

```
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        DecorationFragment fragment = new DecorationFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment,"decoration_fragment");
        ft.commit();
```

I have 2 objects in the Fragment. I want to handle their click event in the Activity.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_decoration, container, false);

    mChangeTextColorButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.changeTextColorButton);
    mColorPallette = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.color_pallette_linearView);
    return rootView;
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can use `onAttach()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, but perhaps this is what you're looking for:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onAttachFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

> `void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment)`
>
> Called when a fragment is attached to the activity.
>
> This is called after the attached fragment's `onAttach` and before the attached fragment's `onCreate` if the fragment has not yet had a previous call to `onCreate`.